# Returning multiple results on the same stream connection to implement HTML5 Server Sent Events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I am trying to set up a lightweight HTML5 Server-Sent Event implementation on my MVC 4 Web, without using one of the libraries available to implement sockets and similars. 
The lightweight approach I am trying is:

**Client side**:
`EventSource` (or `jquery.eventsource` for IE)

**Server side**:
long polling with `AsynchController` (sorry for dropping here the raw test code but just to give an idea)

```
public class HTML5testAsyncController : AsyncController
    {
        private static int curIdx = 0;
        private static BlockingCollection<string> _data = new BlockingCollection<string>();
        static HTML5testAsyncController()
        {
            addItems(10);
        }
 //adds some test messages
        static void addItems(int howMany)
        {
            _data.Add("started");
            for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
            {
                _data.Add("HTML5 item" + (curIdx++).ToString());
            } _data.Add("ended");
        }

// here comes the async action, 'Simple'
        public void SimpleAsync()
        {
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var result = string.Empty; var sb = new StringBuilder();
                string serializedObject = null;
            //wait up to 40 secs that a message arrives
                if (_data.TryTake(out result, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(40000)))
                {
                    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    serializedObject = ser.Serialize(new { item = result, message = "MSG content" });
                    sb.AppendFormat("data: {0}\n\n", serializedObject);
                }
                AsyncManager.Parameters["serializedObject"] = serializedObject;
                AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
            });
        }
  // callback which returns the results on the stream
        public ActionResult SimpleCompleted(string serializedObject)
        { ServerSentEventResult sar = new ServerSentEventResult(); 
            sar.Content = () => { return serializedObject; };
            return sar;

        }
  //pushes the data on the stream in a format conforming HTML5 SSE
        public class ServerSentEventResult : ActionResult
        {
            public ServerSentEventResult() { }
            public delegate string GetContent(); 
            public GetContent Content { get; set; }        
            public int Version { get; set; }
            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                if (context == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
                } if (this.Content != null)
                {
                    HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                    // this is the content type required by chrome 6 for server sent events              
                    response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";

                    response.BufferOutput = false;                // this is important because chrome fails with a "failed to load resource" error if the server attempts to put the char set after the content type          
                    response.Charset = null;
                    string[] newStrings = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Last-Event-ID");
                    if (newStrings == null || newStrings[0] != this.Version.ToString())
                    {
                        string value = this.Content();
                        response.Write(string.Format("data:{0}\n\n", value));
                        //response.Write(string.Format("id:{0}\n", this.Version));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.Write("");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is on the server side as there is still a big gap between the expected result and what's actually going on.

**Expected result**:

- `EventSource` opens a stream connection to the server,
- the server keeps it open for a *safe* time (say, 2 minutes) so that I am protected from thread leaking from dead clients,
- as new message events are received by the server (and enqueued to a thread safe collection such as `BlockingCollection`) they are pushed in the open stream to the client:

  - message 1 received at T+0ms, pushed to the client at T+x
  - message 2 received at **T+200ms**, pushed to the client at **T+x+200ms**

**Actual behaviour**:

- `EventSource` opens a stream connection to the server,
- the server keeps it open until a message event arrives (thanks to long polling)
- once a message is received, MVC pushes the message and closes the connection.
- `EventSource` has to reopen the connection and this happens after a couple of seconds.

  - message 1 received at T+0ms, pushed to the client at T+x
  - message 2 received at **T+200ms**, pushed to the client at **T+x+3200ms**

This is not OK as it defeats the purpose of using SSE as the clients start again reconnecting as in normal polling and message delivery gets delayed.

Now, *the question*:
is there a native way to keep the connection open after sending the first message and sending further messages on the same connection?

Comment: i hate it when  people just call the framework "mvc". Same goes for windows -- it was supposed to means those glassy pane.

Comment: apologies J-16, I thought that concision was more important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of relying on SimpleComplete to send the data, you want to send the data using [Response.Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush.aspx). By doing an AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement(), you're telling the AsyncController that you're finished processing the request and you're ready to send the response and close the connection. Instead, you avoid calling OutStandingOperations.Decrement() until the connection is lost, etc. Whenever you want to push a message to the client, you directly call [Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and Response.Flush from some background thread. Also, AsyncControllers have a default timeout after which they automatically close the connection. To get around that, you'll want to use the [NoAsyncTimeoutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.noasynctimeoutattribute.aspx) for the relevant actions.

As a side note, AsyncController's interface doesn't really allow a clean way of implementing a SSE stream; I would have personally implemented a [HttpTaskAsyncHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httptaskasynchandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) given that I was using Asp.NET MVC 4.

Comment: wow thanks this is indeed good help. Should have thought of the flushing. yes, I am using Asp.NET MVC 4 - I'll try to work out an approach to `HttpTaskAsyncHandler` which I have never used - if you have got any tip readily available, please share

Comment: Well the only tip, in terms of code, I have is to look into the code that SignalR has. They have an implementation, which might require you to understand a few more concepts, of SSE which makes use of the new MVC 4 features. Another tip, use Response.FlushAsync. Asp.NET 4.5 will be making use of I/O completiton ports a lot more.